# On load of a dynamic control in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dynamic

I want to change the attr/css of a dynamically added control according to the value of another dynamic control.
 For eg.

HTML

```
<input type="button" id="btnAdd" value="Add Div"/><br/><br/>
```

Script

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#btnAdd').on('click', function(){
        $('<div>Red</div><br/>').appendTo('body');
      });
});
```

At document.ready, the dynamic controls are not loaded. I have to perform my code after the dynamic controls are loaded to DOM.

I was trying the below code but didn't work

```
 $('div').on('load', function() {
      $('div').css('color', 'red')
  });
```

Please treat the above code as an example only. From the above eg, I am expecting to do my code in the load event of my dynamic control and not on the click event of the button.  (Jquery version 1.7)

Eg 2.
[See Here](https://jsfiddle.net/xpvt214o/326073/), The "Fired On Load." is not logged.

**EDIT :**
This is what exactly I am trying to do but not working.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(document).on('load', '#TimeRangeCondition #StartTime', function () {
    $(this).attr("placeholder", "00:00").blur();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way:

```
$(document).on('load', 'div', function() {
    $(this).css('color', 'red')
});
```

Comment: Thanks Himanshu, but this didn't help. Please see my edit with link to a demo .

Comment: These two selectors `#TimeRangeCondition #StartTime` are in parent child relation or they are two different elements?

Comment: StartTime is a control inside TimeRangeCondition

Comment: So whats happening? its not picking up `StartTime` yea? But why are you using parent element reference as it already accessible through its `id` ?

Comment: you can refer the link i provide as eg2 for an idea of the issue. I don't think it has anything to do with the ids. There might be another controls which have StartTime inside it, so using it along with parent id. I want the StartTime to be attached with placeholder attr on load of the control.